# Can my plant produce hormones that cause ultra-violent behavior?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, humans, flora, biochemistry

A human without hormones or pheromones could be compared to something more like a plant, tool, or simply a reactionless amalgamation of cells without purpose, fears, and emotions. Such a person wouldn't thrive and instead would be out-competed. Most mental illnesses are linked to chemical imbalances and psychiatrists often manage to solve problems with a few doses of hormones: happy pills, calm pills, courage pills, relax pills, stop-being-so-horny pills.

A fast spreading plant capable of releasing ultra violence hormones is taking over the world. Everyone is struggling to not kill one another over the sound chewing or snoring. Children are punching walls until their hands are exposed to bone because their preferred youtuber hasn't uploaded today or they didn't catch that poke'mon and the smallest teen angst is the daily school shooting.

- The plant in question can't release hormones in the air and even if it did, it wouldn't work.
- The plant instead is eaten by livestock and then processed into a version that can be absorbed.
- In this world everyone is consuming their violence pills in the form of a cheesecake or a barbecue.

Is there any hormone which makes human less tolerant and more violent that plants can produce as a side effect? Preferably a hormone which humans can't easily build tolerance and resistance to. Do I need to handwave the chemistry side of this hormone?

Comment: I... don't understand the relationship between your "hormonless" person and your question about which "anger" hormone can a plant produce. Maybe you should remove the person part, focus more on your issue.

Comment: @Tortliena fear that the question might have been seen as off-topic and moved to a chemistry site or a biology or maybe even psychology one... and then that site would close the question as being off-topic. Thus wanted to first explain what kind of situation and worldbuilding problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Your question is about the plant, not the über-person, so talking about the person wouldn't make your question much more on topic. If it was off-topic ;p. You're "creating" a plant "for your world" which produces directly human hormones. On top of that, I don't think there's much of these in the real world (even though there are many which can make _you_ produce hormones. Hmm... Cocoa...) so don't worry too much about being off-topic :).

Comment: @Tortliena I agree. There is nothing useful in the first paragraph, and this weakens the entire question.

Comment: Google things that cause paranoia. Plants already produce things like cocaine. Imagine a plant that induces wild manic episodes followed by severe withdrawal symptoms and paranoid hallucinations. Alternately, it disables a person's ability to sleep, leading to increasing psychosis and delusions. Fun stuff. https://www.cumberlandheights.org/blogs/addiction-and-paranoia/

Answer (score 4):

There are several existing plant based species that produce steroids in general and testosterone specifically.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6680614/

http://www.phytopharmajournal.com/Vol4_Issue2_12.pdf

It seems plausible to me that some sort of alien/mutated steroid producing plant could overwhelm humanity with "roid rage".

https://www.apa.org/monitor/oct02/moremale

Comment: wait, does that have to be specifically testosterone? I heard it has funny effects on females....

Comment: No, in theory "anabolic-androgenic steroids" such as (but not limited to) testosterone potentially lead to risky/aggressive behavior. Testosterone is just the main version that our bodies produce.

Comment: @Green Yes, testosterone itself is [perfect for transgender treatments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masculinizing_hormone_therapy). Well, towards one way at least. However, note that the answer also talk about steroids, which have other effects.

Comment: One has to consume a lot of testosterone to substantially change the behavior. It however may be some other *fictitious* steroid which has a much stronger psychological effect.

Answer (score 0):

Neurons regularly grow from the olfactory epithelium of the nose to glomeruli of the olfactory bulb of the brain.  Neurons of the olfactory bulb project via the olfactory tract (and lateral olfactory stria) to the amygdala.  The amygdala is the seat of strong emotions, especially fear, but at times the frenzied reactions of animals stimulated in the amygdala has been interpreted by observers as rage.

Your plants produce male gametophytes, i.e. pollen, which is breathed by the victim.  The pollen germinates on the olfactory epithelium, producing a pollen tube that follows the path of the olfactory neurons, either by contact or chemokine signals, until it reaches the olfactory bulb.  It then releases its pollen, which contain potent protein toxins that are transported by the cells of the olfactory tract.  When these toxins reach the amygdala, they cause extensive damage and hyperstimulation.  The amygdala's aberrant signal (probably not the toxin) is then carried along the stria terminalis to the bed nucleus of the stria terminalis, which communicates extreme hormonal impulses to the hypothalamus.  All these structures affect behavior -  even the olfactory nerve, which also communicates to an olfactory tubercle that influences feelings of disgust, such as whether eating your neighbor's entrails is disgusting.

Answer (score 0):

Bath salts (the drug) is the street name for synthetic cathinone, which naturally occurs in the khat plant. Bath salts can cause hallucinations and have led to things like people [eating other people's faces](https://abcnews.go.com/US/face-eating-attack-possibly-linked-bath-salts-miami/story?id=16451452)... could be a good candidate.